# How to concat multiple js files inside a function in gulp

Tags: javascript, jquery, gulp, gulp-concat

I need to concat all the specific files within their corresponding functions using Gulp with the following folder structure:

```
modules
  - header
    - document.ready.js
    - functions.js
    - window.resize.js
  - main
    - document.ready.js
    - functions.js
    - window.resize.js
  - footer
    - document.ready.js
    - functions.js
    - window.resize.js
```

The final file should look like this:

```
//All functions.js files concated.

$(document).ready(function(){
    //All document.ready.js files concated.
});

$(window).resize(function(){
    //All window.resize.js files concated.
});
```

Does anyone have any idea how to do this with Gulp?

I have this so far:

```
gulp.task('modules', function() {
    gulp.src('js/modules/**/document.ready.js')
        .pipe(concat('document.ready.js'));

    var source = gulp.src('generator/assets/js/document.ready.js', {read: false});
    var target = gulp.src('js/modules/modules.js');

    target.pipe(inject(source), {starttag: '<!-- inject:head:js -->'})
        .pipe(gulp.dest('generator/assets/js'));
});
```

The var target file has this content:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    <!-- inject:head:js -->
    <!-- endinject -->
});
```

when I run gulp, the file is simply copied and the injection is not made. Any idea what might be going wrong?

Comment: What have your tried so far?

Comment: @Lowkase I have no idea where to start, I do not know Gulp very well...

Comment: I won't do all your work for you, but this should point you in the right direction: https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-concat Install it from the web by command-lining to your directory and entering `npm install gulp-concat`

Comment: @Katana314 My problem is to insert all the concated files into the final file...

Comment: to inesrt use gulp-inject

Comment: @Katana314 and now? Have some problem here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem with this:

```
var gfi = require("gulp-file-insert");

gulp.task('modules', function() {
    gulp.src('js/modules/**/document.ready.js')
        .pipe(concat('document.ready.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('generator/assets/js'));

    gulp.src('js/modules/modules.js')
        .pipe(gfi({
            "/* file 1 */": "generator/assets/js/document.ready.js"
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('generator/assets/js'));
});
```

To replace file content you can use gulp-file-insert